# Strange Xbox one noises

Tags: xbox-one

I have had my Xbox one for a while now but for the past few months I think, there is this strange noise coming from it sounding sort like a meep I not sure how to explain it, but it does it over and over again I'm not sure if it's the hard drive or something, but I just want confirmation to make sure something isn't wrong

Comment: is anything happening when it is making this strange noise? like games crashing or OS issues?

Comment: By “meep” sound, are you sure it’s not the “bleep-bloop” sound you get when you obtain an achievement?

Comment: There is no crashing with my games but what scares me though is because i have been trying to play the newer and bigger games like forza horizon 5 and I feel like the Xbox is overheating, but the noise happens when it boots up too, like I put my ear next onto of the fan it seems to be in the middle of the fan, so its a internal noise. Does this help?

Comment: Could be a bad fan bearing if you hear it when starting up the console. Bad bearings tend to be noisiest when they are first spun up. Would you perhaps be able to record this sound and upload it for us to hear?